# Generic clas with inheritance can't be used in mapping

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
interface BaseComponentData {}

class ComponentBase<T extends BaseComponentData = BaseComponentData> {

    constructor(public id: string, protected _componentData: T, protected parent?: ComponentBase) { }
}

class ActionButtonComponent extends ComponentBase {}

const COMPONENT_MAP: { [key: string]: typeof ComponentBase } = {
    'actionButton': ActionButtonComponent
}
```

and it gives me this error when compiling:

```
Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
Type 'new (id: string, _componentData: BaseComponentData, parent?: ComponentBase<BaseComponentData>) => ActionButtonComponent' is not assignable to type 'new <T extends BaseComponentData = BaseComponentData>(id: string, _componentData: T, parent?: ComponentBase<BaseComponentData>) => ComponentBase<...>'.
Construct signature return types 'ActionButtonComponent' and 'ComponentBase<T>' are incompatible.
    The types of '_componentData' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'BaseComponentData' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'BaseComponentData' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseComponentData'.

'actionButton': ActionButtonComponent
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

const COMPONENT_MAP: { [key: string]: typeof ComponentBase } = {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The expected type comes from this index signature.
```

If I add a generic type to the map like so:

```
const COMPONENT_MAP: { [key: string]: typeof ComponentBase<BaseComponentData> } = {
    'actionButton': ActionButtonComponent
}
```

I don't get any warnings in vscode but when I compile I get this:

```
tsTest.ts: 11: 59 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

11 const COMPONENT_MAP: { [key: string]: typeof ComponentBase<BaseComponentData> } = {
                                                             ~

tsTest.ts: 11: 79 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

11 const COMPONENT_MAP: { [key: string]: typeof ComponentBase<BaseComponentData> } = {
                                                                                 ~
```

which I don't fully understand.

Is there a way I can have a mapping of string to class where the class is restricted to a type?

Comment: You likely to have different VSCode (selected in `{}` icon in bottom right corner) and workspace (installed in package.json) versions of Typescript.

Comment: What's your TS version? VSCode use latest, 5.0.4 or something

Comment: Typescript version is 4.1.6 and vscode is 5.1.6. I've changed the vscode one and I'm now getting more consistent errors.

Comment: If you have a reliance on an old version of TypeScript please [edit] the question to explicitly state it (and consider upgrading no matter what; TS moves fast as a language and being stuck on older versions gets increasingly untenable over time).  If not, what specifically is the issue here?  Either way please [edit] the question so it doesn't seem to be about some VSCode.